# How to express this using matrix operations?

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix $A$:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 &3 &1\\
  7 &5 &2\\
  4& 3& 7\\
  8& 2& 1\\
  3& 9& 6\\
  4 &5 &2
\end{pmatrix}$$

and a matrix $B$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    2& 9& 1\\
    4& 3 &8\\
    9& 7& 3\\
    4& 4& 2\\
    6& 5& 7\\
    2 &9& 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to compute $C$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1\cdot2+3\cdot9+1\cdot1\\
    7\cdot4+5\cdot3+2\cdot8\\
    4\cdot9+3\cdot7+7\cdot3\\
    8\cdot4+2\cdot4+1\cdot2\\
    3\cdot6+9\cdot5+6\cdot7\\
    4\cdot2+5\cdot9+2\cdot2
\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I express this purely using matrix operations?

Comment: Would you tell why are you interested in this? This can be done via $$
C = (A.B)\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A.B$ denotes the element-wise product which is not quite  a *pure* matrix operation (although it is implemented e.g. in MATLAB)

Comment: Also $\operatorname{diag}(AB^T)$ gives the vector. (Horizontal or vertical, depending on how we define the operator $\operatorname{diag}$.)

Comment: I am interested in this because I am trying to compute the cost function of a neural network. I have a 5000 x 10 output vector and a 5000 x 10 training vector. I. e. it is classifying a training set of 5000 things into 10 classes.

Comment: thank you for your responses; i am trying to understand/verify them.

Answer (score 1):

'Switch' the $B$ matrix around with a transpose: $A B^T$. Let $e_1 = (1,0,0,0,0,0)^T$, $e_2 = (0,1,0,0,0,0)^T$, etc. Then:
$$C = \sum_{i=1}^6 (e_i^T A B^T e_i)e_i$$

Comment: Agks doesn't want the first column but the diagonal, no?

Comment: thank you -- can the summation be expressed in pure matrix terms?

Comment: If you mean by just products, transpositions and multiplication by constant matrices then I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

From a non-MATLAB perspective, you're just taking the dot product of the rows of each matrix so

$$ c_i = \sum_{j=1}^3 a_{ij}b_{ij} $$